# Unable to query after upgrading Diesel to v2 (Rust)

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

Getting the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
    --> src/u/r/api/products/articles.rs:17:69
     |
17   |     let query = web::block(move || articles::table.load::<Articles>(&*connection).unwrap()).await;
     |                                                    ---------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
     |                                                    |
     |                                                    arguments to this function are incorrect
     |
     = note: expected mutable reference `&mut _`
                        found reference `&PgConnection`
note: associated function defined here
    --> /Users/b/.cargo/registry/src/github.com/diesel-2.0.2/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1497:8
     |
1497 |     fn load<'query, U>(self, conn: &mut Conn) -> QueryResult<Vec<U>>
     |        ^^^^
```

I am using Diesel v2, it worked before I upgraded to the latest version.

What am I doing wrong?

```
use crate::u::db::connection::DbPool;
use actix_web::{get, web, HttpResponse, Responder};

#[get("/product/articles")]
pub async fn list(db_pool: web::Data<DbPool>) -> impl Responder {
    use crate::u::db::models::products::Articles;
    use crate::u::db::schemas::products::articles;

    let connection = db_pool.get();
    if let Err(e) = connection {
        return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(format!("E1-{:?}", e));
    }

    let connection = connection.unwrap();

    let query = web::block(move || articles::table.load::<Articles>(&*connection).unwrap()).await;

    if let Err(e) = query {
        return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(format!("E2-{:?}", e));
    }

    let q = query.expect("oops not Ok");

    HttpResponse::Ok().json(q)
}
```

models/products.rs

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use uuid::Uuid;

use crate::u::db::schemas::products::*;

#[derive(Queryable, Debug, Identifiable, serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
#[table_name = "articles"]
#[primary_key(prod_art_pvt_uuid)]
pub struct Articles {
    pub prod_art_pvt_uuid: Uuid,
    pub prod_art_pub_uuid: Uuid,
    pub prod_article_pub_id: i32,
    pub t: DateTime<Utc>,
}
```

db/connection.rs

```
use crate::u::config;

use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use diesel::r2d2::ConnectionManager;
use r2d2::Pool;

pub type DbPool = r2d2::Pool<ConnectionManager<PgConnection>>;

pub fn get_pool() -> DbPool {
    let url: String = config::get("database_url");

    println!("Connecting to database...");
    let manager = ConnectionManager::<PgConnection>::new(url);

    Pool::builder()
        .build(manager)
        .expect("Failed to create database connection pool.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message already indicates what needs to be change. The important part is that one:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
    --> src/u/r/api/products/articles.rs:17:69
     |
17   |     let query = web::block(move || articles::table.load::<Articles>(&*connection).unwrap()).await;
     |                                                    ---------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
     |                                                    |
     |                                                    arguments to this function are incorrect
     |
     = note: expected mutable reference `&mut _`
                        found reference `&PgConnection`
```

As you can see there you need to change the argument of the `load` function to a mutable reference. You try to pass an immutable reference, which is something that's not accepted by the underlying function.

I recommend to checkout the [Diesel Migration guide](https://diesel.rs/guides/migration_guide.html) which contains an overview of most user-facing breaking changes of the 2.0 release.